# Sql case in case

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have this select:

```
current_date - min(case when psi.status = 'OPEN' and psi.due_date < current_date then psi.due_date end) as has_overdue_days
```

Return **has_overdue_days** its okay, but other rows are blanks in result, how to make case in case that if return blank shows '0'

Comment: Why don't you/can't you use FILTER() ? Makes at least your code a bit readable. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `coalesce(<expr/your sql>, 0)`. It chooses the first non-null value from the expression list, have a 0 at the end will return 0 when blank